# Java - Can't download image from internet if src has a hyphen

Tags: java, image, hyperlink, save

I have a program that involves downloading an image from the internet from said image's src, and it works perfectly most of the time, however if the src of the image has a "-" in the address I get an IOException.

```
BufferedImage image = null;
fileName = emailFirst + "_at_" + emailLast + " (" + fullName + ")";

URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
image = ImageIO.read(url);

System.out.println("DIRECTORY: " + directory);
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new java.io.File(directory + "\\" + fileName + ".jpg"));
```

The only instances where this fails to work is when the url has a hyphen such as this link within "wp-content"

https://www.applicoinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Employee_Alex_Moazed.jpg

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit your post and show the specific IO exception you get and its stacktrace?

Comment: Use a URLEncoder and it should work

Answer (score 2):

If you check out the documentation for the [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class you will see this (emphasis mine)

> The URL class **does not itself encode or decode any URL components** according to the escaping mechanism defined in RFC2396. It is the responsibility of the caller to encode any fields, which need to be escaped prior to calling URL, and also to decode any escaped fields, that are returned from URL.

To properly encode it you must initialize a [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)  with your URL string, and call the [`toURL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#toURL--) method to get the encoded URL.

Comment: URLEncoder is *not* for encoding URL components, despite its name.  URLEncoder is for encoding data using [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1).  The two encodings are similar but not the same.  To properly percent-encode URL components, create a [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) and call its toURL method.

Comment: @VGR You're very right - I was a bit too fast there. I've changed my answer.